# ExcelDna xll add-in not shown but functions are visible, why?

Tags: excel-dna

I created an ExcelDna Add-in by following the steps on ExcelDna webpage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ExcelDna.Integration;
namespace ExcelCalculator
{
    public static class ExcelDnaTest
    {
        [ExcelFunction(Description = "My first .NET function")]
        public static string HelloDna(string name)
        {
            return "HelloDna " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling the project generates the following files:

```
ExcelCalculator.dll
ExcelCalculator.pdb
ExcelCalculator-Addin.dna
ExcelCalculator-Addin.xll
ExcelCalculator-Addin-packed.xll
ExcelCalculator-Addin64.dna
ExcelCalculator-Addin64.xll
ExcelCalculator-Addin64-packed.xll
```

Then I dragged ExcelCalculator-Addin.xll into my Excel 2016 x86 session, I can successfully run the function and see the expected result. However I could not see ExcelCalculator addin anywhere. It is not in Options -> Addins -> Excel-addins

Does anyone happen to know why? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not expected to be in the Options -> Add-Ins list unless you've installed it in Excel explicitly. Just opening the add-in using File -> Open does not install it, and it won't load automatically the next time you start Excel.

If you add it to the Add-Ins dialog by browsing and the checking the add-in, it will load every time.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Govert.